# How to show/hide form fields in listing view based on a condition in GeoDirectory?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I enjoy GeoDirectory, and the conditions for custom fields work great in the 'add new' forms. However, I want to hide street addresses for a certain listing category and cannot find a way to do this.
I basically want the conditions to affect the list view,  but also accept any workaround. [image: conditions for custom fields, unfortunately in german]